# pychef api pychef ChefServerNotFoundError

Tags: python, chef-infra, pychef

I'm using chef server, configuring few different nodes / environments.

when asking for `env` attributes using the pychef api, few times in a row (when refreshing a web page using python server calling chef server) im getting `ChefServerNotFoundError` (the first few times are fine, and third exception is raised)

I guess that there is kind of firewall / anti ddos attacks on this server, but i can not figure out how to edit these settings.

anyone have any idea?

this is a part of the method (that is called 3 times and throws an exception):

```
env_nodes = Search('node').query('chef_environment:  {0}'.format(env_name))
nodes_dict = {}
for n in env_nodes:
    node = Node(n['name'])
    nodes_dict[node.name] = node['ipaddress']`
```

and this is the traceback:

```
File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\chef\search.py", line 91, in __getitem__
  row_value = self.data['rows'][value]
File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\chef\search.py", line 59, in data
  self._data = self.api[self.url]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`
```

Comment: Please include the code snippet that is throwing the error, or at least a traceback.

Answer (score 0):

When using PyChef in a webapp or other multi-threaded system you should really pass in the API object explicitly. There is a system to track a default API target in a threadlocal for the purposes of making simple scripts easier, but in retrospect this was probably a mistake as it leads to these confusing issues. This would be a better version of that code, also faster:

```
nodes_dict =  {row.object.name: row.object['ipaddress'] for row in Search('node', 'chef_environment:{}'.format(env_name), api=api)}
```

Where `api` is the return value of `chef.autoconfigure()` or some other ChefAPI object.